# How to write a boost::lambda functor that returns a new functor

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-lambda

How can I write a lambda expression with two placeholders, one for the callable object, and one for the function argument, such that supplying the callable object first returns a unary function.

In the example below, `generate` should be a lambda expression with the first placeholder for the callable object itself, and the second placeholder for the argument. Calling `generate(c)` should return a unary function that is only missing the function call argument. In fact, it somehow returns type `bool` already, as proved by the static assert.

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

struct Arg {
};

struct Callable : std::unary_function<Arg, bool> {
    bool operator()( Arg const& a ) const { return true; }
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) {
    BOOST_AUTO(generate, boost::lambda::bind(boost::lambda::_1, boost::lambda::protect(boost::lambda::_1)));

    Callable c;
    BOOST_AUTO(fn, generate(c));

    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_same<BOOST_TYPEOF(fn), bool>::value));
    Arg a;
    bool b = fn(a);
    _ASSERT(b==true);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using Boost.Phoenix the answer would have been a little easier:

```
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>

struct callable
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    bool operator()(int) const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using phx::bind;
    using phx::lambda;
    using phx::arg_names::_1;
    using phx::local_names::_a;

    auto generate = lambda(_a = _1)[bind(_a, _1)];
    auto fn = generate(callable());

    bool b = fn(8);
}
```

Not that this solution is far more generic than the version posted by the OT. It can be used with any unary function object, no matter what argument, no matter what return type.

The downside, you need to use the current boost trunk ...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in case we gradually introduce boost::phoenix into our code base. boost::bind, boost::lambda::bind, boost::phoenix::bind -- this is getting a bit out of hand, isn't it? :-)

Comment: It is. Phoenix attempts to unify these three. For example, phoenix::bind is able to perform everything that boost::bind does (it passes all testcases from Boost.Bind) with the addition of providing way more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own problem, albeit not as elegantly as I had hoped:

```
   struct FCreateBind {
        typedef boost::_bi::bind_t<bool, Callable, boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >  > result_type;
        result_type operator()( Callable const& c ) const {
            return boost::bind<bool>(c, _1);
        }
};
BOOST_AUTO(generate, boost::bind(FCreateBind(), _1));

   BOOST_AUTO(fn, generate(Callable());
   bool b = fn(Arg());
```

Of course, in this simple example I could just write `BOOST_AUTO(generate, boost::lambda_1)` since `Callable` itself is the callable object. But I was looking for a way to set the arguments of `Callable` beforehand so the generated function `fn` is a nullary function. This solution would let me do this inside `FCreateBind`.

`FCreateBind` can probably be eliminated as well, but I have not yet figured out how to define the pointer to the overloaded global function `boost::bind`.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, the following code
might meet your purpose:

```
template< class R >
struct FCreateBind {
  typedef boost::function< R() > result_type;

  template< class T, class U >
  result_type operator()( T const& x, U const& y ) const {
    return boost::bind( x, y );
  }
};

int main() {
  BOOST_AUTO( generate, boost::bind( FCreateBind< bool >(), Callable(), _1 ) );
  BOOST_AUTO( fn, generate( Arg() ) );
  bool b = fn();
}
```

That being said, probably this isn't as pretty as the questioner
expects...
As you mentioned, if we specify one of the overloads of `boost::bind`
explicitly, `FCreateBind` wouldn't be needed.
However, as far as I saw, there seems not to be the portable way to specify
the overload.
So, in this case, probably we have to depend on the internal of `boost`.
For your information, the following code could be compiled when I tested:

```
int main() {
  namespace bb = boost::_bi; // Sorry, for brevity
  bb::bind_t< bb::unspecified, Callable, bb::list1< bb::value< Arg > > >
    (*bi)( Callable, Arg ) = boost::bind< bb::unspecified, Callable, Arg >;
  BOOST_AUTO( generate, boost::bind( bi, Callable(), _1 ) );
  BOOST_AUTO( fn, generate( Arg() ) );
  bool b = fn();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The first solution is pretty much what I proposed myself in my own answer but using boost::function as a result_type. Whenever the explicit type can be used I prefer it over wrapping a functor in boost::function. Thanks though for figuring out how to write the boost::bind functor down.